# Nice application to track exceptions in Java?

Tags: java, exception, tomcat, tracking

Is there an application or something out there that will track a Tomcat application's exceptions?

Basically, I want an easier way of viewing problem areas in my application without having to read a long log file.

Comment: Setting the logging level to ERROR or FATAL or something like that would not make it easier? or do you mean that there are so many problems going on in the system over a long period of time (days, weeks etc)?

Comment: What I want to see is an overview of problems.  Like it would list what classes (or whatever) have been throwing exceptions and then be able to view that in more detail (by viewing the actual log entries, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be better off over on [serverfault](http://serverfault.com) where you'll find similiar questions like [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/96720/open-source-tomcat-log-viewer) with options in the answers for you to try out along with its related questions.

Answer (score 1):

I got one application called ErrorApp(http://errorapp.com) to track exceptions from applications.

Currently it's working with Ruby on Rails Applications.

But for java people are doing. you can see here https://github.com/rubyrockers/errorapp_notifier-java

It's free for many projects.

Answer (score 0):

There is plenty of application to help you parse and analyse logs. A basic but powerful one is [Chainsaw](http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/index.html).